# HighCharts – no background and shadow on tooltip under Firefox

Tags: highcharts

Having a chart with two series of data and its own tooltip content handling, the background and shadow of the first displayed element is not rendered correctly. This only happens on the Firefox browser. On the Chrome browser or Edge this error does not occur.

```
chart: {
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    useHTML: true,
    split: true,
  },
  series: [{
    softThreshold: true,
    showInLegend: false,
    step: "center",
    tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function () {
        return `<span>Custom formatter...</span>`;
      }
    },
    type: 'column',
    data: [[1706137200000,10], [1706139200000,13]],
  }, {
    softThreshold: true,
    showInLegend: false,
    type: 'line',
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function () {
        return `<span>Custom formatter...</span>`;
      }
    },
    marker: {
      enabled: true,
      radius: 4
    },
    data: [[1706137200000,10], [1706139200000,13]],
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wpy423L9/5/

[image]

Comment: It might be a bug which you can report on the github page https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose ; as a workaround you can move the `useHTML: true, ` option to the `plotOptions.series.tooltip` as in the following demo https://jsfiddle.net/d26bsyjt/44/